# How to get Barcode type using ZXing library

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner

I use ZXing library for Barcode Scanning.

I am using 2 classes of ZXing, IntentIntegrator.java and IntentResult.java in my project.

And I can easily get code from the barcode image and format of the barcode image from the below code,

```
public void onClick(View view)
{
    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
    integrator.initiateScan();
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) 
{
      IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
      if (scanResult != null) 
      {

          String barcode;
          String format;

          barcode=scanResult.getContents();
          format=scanResult.getFormatName();

      }
}
```

Now, My question is how to get the type of the barcode like Text, URL, Address book, Phone Number, Email address.

I need your help guys, Please help!

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a property of the barcode itself but of how you choose to parse the content. The `IntentResult` object doesn't have this information since it leaves parsing to you.

You could include the `core.jar` library as well, and then use the `ResultParser` class on the contents to parse it just like the app would do. Then you get a nice tidy object representing the type and contents of the parsing.

Comment: Hey, Suppose I have included the `core.jar` file to my project.Now can you please help me how to use `ResultParser`.
Actually I am new to android.If you will tell me, then it would be easy for me.

Comment: Not until you try it yourself, can show what you've tried and specifically what your next question is.

Answer (score 0):

As Sean said, you can't access it.

But you might use a simple method to retrieve that barcode format.

The format are not declared final (whereas they are constants). So you might not use a switch. but With a simple elseif : (after imports)

```
public static BarcodeFormat getBarCodeFormatWith(final String s) {

    if (s.equals(EAN_8.toString())){
        return EAN_8;
    } else if (s.equals(EAN_13.toString())) {
        return EAN_13;
    } else if (s.equals(UPC_A.toString())) {
        return UPC_A;
    } else if (s.equals(QR_CODE.toString())) {
        return QR_CODE;
    } else if (s.equals(CODE_39.toString())) {
        return CODE_39;
    } else if (s.equals(CODE_128.toString())) {
        return CODE_128;
    } else if (s.equals(ITF.toString())) {
        return ITF;
    } else if (s.equals(PDF_417.toString())) {
        return PDF_417;
    } else if (s.equals(CODABAR.toString())) {
        return CODABAR;
    } else if (s.equals(DATA_MATRIX.toString())) {
        return DATA_MATRIX;
    } else if (s.equals(AZTEC.toString())) {
        return AZTEC;
    } else if (s.equals(PDF_417.toString())) {
        return PDF_417;
    }  else if (s.equals(CODE_93.toString())) {
        return CODE_93;
    }  else if (s.equals(MAXICODE.toString())) {
        return MAXICODE;
    }  else if (s.equals(UPC_E.toString())) {
        return UPC_E;
    }  else if (s.equals(UPC_EAN_EXTENSION.toString())) {
        return UPC_EAN_EXTENSION;
    }  else if (s.equals(RSS_14.toString())) {
        return RSS_14;
    }  else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Done, enjoy :)
working on Zxing v3.4.0